# Dynamic CSS styling using calc in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a list of items, and I am parsing them with `*ngFor` loop. I need to add some margin to these items base on indexes, and doing it with `[style.margin-left.%]`.

```
<div *ngFor="let d of dates" [style.margin-left.%]="d.marginLeft">{{d.date | date: 'MMM'}}</div>
```

But this does not quite correct for me. Code is parsing like: `margin-left: x%` and I need something like this for end result: `margin-left: calc(x% - 5px)`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create string of **calc(x% - 5px)** like this.

```
[style.margin-left]="'calc(' + d.marginLeft + '% - 5px'"
```